# How to call SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment inside onCreateView()

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using getChildFragmentManager() in my application, I want to call this below code inside Fragment OncreateView().Can any one help to to achieve this functionality,actually i have already kept the code ,I got error in Line number 2?

```
   1.  SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager()
   2.                 .findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
   3.         autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
   4.         autocompleteFragment.setHint("Select a Location");
```

**ERROR :** java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(**com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener)' on a null object reference**  com.example.sample.fragments.LocationFragment.onCreateView(LocationFragment.java:2)

```
                                                                        at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment` your activity should be implementing `AppCompatActivity` (or `FragmentActivity` and use `getSupportFragmentManager()`) to reach your fragments.

Or the other way around, create a `PlaceAutoCompleteFragment` instead of `SupportPlaceAutoCompleteFragment`.

Check *Support* part of Option #1 here
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

ps. I assume you already have `R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment` in your layout xml.